# dynamic input slicing for tensorflow dynamic RNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, lstm

Considering an RNN trained with phrases of different lengths to predict the next letter, given a string.

Say I have the following phrases as my dataset:

```
I really want to go to work
the book has arrived
I will buy the red car
```

The input sequence would be:

```
I really want to go to wor
the book has arrive
I will buy the red ca
```

The labels would be:

```
 really want to go to work
he book has arrived
 will buy the red car
```

Can this be done with tensorflow? The slice function seems to only work with sentences of the same length.

Comment: Would it perhaps make more sense to only give the missing letters as labels, and compare those with the last letter in each line of the output?

Comment: @MPA it would not. why would it?

Comment: Then you don't have to slice